# new windows laptop or upgrade to 15inch macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade

My budget is around 1800. I already bought 13'' macbook pro 2011 from microcenter for 1093 (including tax). This was my first macbook and I'm impressed, but only downsize of it is that 13'' seems a little bit small for me. Since I have been using 15.4 windows laptop for 6 years now, I have to decide.

1. Upgrade 13'' to 15''. I need to pay around $830 more.
2. By a dell xps 15 around $600.
3. buy a new monitor since I use my laptop at home

What do you guys think? I know :) this is an apple forum and I can only decide this question, but I just wanted to ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for the monitor. You'll then have dual displays when you're at your desk, and a smaller, lighter portable when you're not. Best of both worlds, *and* the cheapest solution. :-)